# Assumptions in Changepoint analysis (EnvCpt) of Time Series

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, change-point

I'm looking to identify changepoints in my time series data. To begin, I've seasonally adjusted the data using JDemetra+. Next, I'll carry out a changepoint analysis utilizing the EnvCpt function in R.

```
adjusted.ts <- ts(data$`Seasonally adjusted`, frequency = 12, start = c(2002, 1))
out=envcpt(adjusted.ts, models=c("trend","trendcpt","trendar1","trendar2","trendar1cpt","trendar2cpt"))
```

This analysis identified the Trend cpt model as the most suitable option based on the BIC criteria

[image]

Now, I'd like to examine the assumptions of the model to determine whether the identified changepoints are actually a result of autocorrelation, genuine changepoints, or merely outliers

Seasonally adjusted time series:

```
        structure(list(Date = c("2002-01-01", "2002-02-01", "2002-03-01", 
"2002-04-01", "2002-05-01", "2002-06-01", "2002-07-01", "2002-08-01", 
"2002-09-01", "2002-10-01", "2002-11-01", "2002-12-01", "2003-01-01", 
"2003-02-01", "2003-03-01", "2003-04-01", "2003-05-01", "2003-06-01", 
"2003-07-01", "2003-08-01", "2003-09-01", "2003-10-01", "2003-11-01", 
"2003-12-01", "2004-01-01", "2004-02-01", "2004-03-01", "2004-04-01", 
"2004-05-01", "2004-06-01", "2004-07-01", "2004-08-01", "2004-09-01", 
"2004-10-01", "2004-11-01", "2004-12-01", "2005-01-01", "2005-02-01", 
"2005-03-01", "2005-04-01", "2005-05-01", "2005-06-01", "2005-07-01", 
"2005-08-01", "2005-09-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-11-01", "2005-12-01", 
"2006-01-01", "2006-02-01", "2006-03-01", "2006-04-01", "2006-05-01", 
"2006-06-01", "2006-07-01", "2006-08-01", "2006-09-01", "2006-10-01", 
"2006-11-01", "2006-12-01", "2007-01-01", "2007-02-01", "2007-03-01", 
"2007-04-01", "2007-05-01", "2007-06-01", "2007-07-01", "2007-08-01", 
"2007-09-01", "2007-10-01", "2007-11-01", "2007-12-01", "2008-01-01", 
"2008-02-01", "2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", 
"2008-07-01", "2008-08-01", "2008-09-01", "2008-10-01", "2008-11-01", 
"2008-12-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-02-01", "2009-03-01", "2009-04-01", 
"2009-05-01", "2009-06-01", "2009-07-01", "2009-08-01", "2009-09-01", 
"2009-10-01", "2009-11-01", "2009-12-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-02-01", 
"2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-07-01", 
"2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-10-01", "2010-11-01", "2010-12-01", 
"2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", 
"2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-08-01", "2011-09-01", "2011-10-01", 
"2011-11-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", 
"2012-04-01", "2012-05-01", "2012-06-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-08-01", 
"2012-09-01", "2012-10-01", "2012-11-01", "2012-12-01", "2013-01-01", 
"2013-02-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", "2013-05-01", "2013-06-01", 
"2013-07-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-09-01", "2013-10-01", "2013-11-01", 
"2013-12-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", 
"2014-05-01", "2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01", "2014-09-01", 
"2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", 
"2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01", "2015-07-01", 
"2015-08-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-12-01", 
"2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", 
"2016-06-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-08-01", "2016-09-01", "2016-10-01", 
"2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", 
"2017-04-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01", "2017-08-01", 
"2017-09-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", 
"2018-02-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-06-01", 
"2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", 
"2018-12-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", 
"2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", "2019-09-01", 
"2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-07-01", 
"2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-12-01", 
"2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-05-01", 
"2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-10-01", 
"2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01", 
"2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-08-01", 
"2022-09-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-12-01", "2023-01-01", 
"2023-02-01", "2023-03-01", "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01"), `Seasonally adjusted` = c(23647673159.4888, 
25201827308.6018, 24366827359.3458, 26029505079.9743, 25559979920.8444, 
25857787410.6745, 27879938573.7661, 28287631050.2125, 29454819291.4043, 
29563661816.7143, 29325865778.7194, 29171476955.4805, 32452801946.364, 
32265241532.498, 32734720210.9602, 34742427062.8356, 35064777820.0594, 
34187133389.579, 36413623045.1169, 35953643380.7173, 38781725254.279, 
40442794203.7472, 39174468821.2227, 43893452077.6581, 38913891448.6586, 
45209245211.0521, 46706957995.1075, 46101384645.3212, 46435307964.5485, 
49881560568.1054, 48785081838.0917, 49305640209.7035, 51733196244.3969, 
51993052959.2766, 57014424721.4712, 58265057086.5058, 55104900509.2123, 
58865781378.6753, 62058232171.7257, 61018578302.492, 60348014899.9779, 
64964366212.9808, 62727227944.3372, 65371022980.7132, 65198276971.5391, 
67483767129.7417, 67470116132.2533, 69066505643.4977, 70103202442.6079, 
72333765233.9056, 79911174012.5089, 75833628360.7261, 75247645585.8265, 
79998464394.2104, 76682580237.3234, 86452620753.7062, 85229413613.3424, 
87404045699.4929, 89415376522.5578, 86346508312.478, 92724845586.1636, 
110312934593.357, 85947289212.9687, 96436965549.6964, 96303267017.0707, 
101628718406.19, 102435822263.076, 105960260371.65, 104709160317.622, 
107030425764.892, 109651007862.845, 104982032048.725, 116595075808.412, 
117954483936.484, 112628234446.872, 118013456940.54, 122632362833.569, 
119362457870.837, 129471215898.278, 128494782927.47, 127358269901.249, 
127733331560.73, 107296389821.753, 101716576187.751, 95591612325.1927, 
88064152477.2527, 93412522584.0753, 91702536266.4921, 89763867191.2935, 
94099171191.1408, 99720011937.9049, 99041022895.6192, 108535158863.742, 
110523663389.131, 106382297464.387, 119310730833.041, 114689614961.149, 
129012168590.117, 115959298744.601, 119869120535.2, 132198860791.678, 
135198260184.171, 137605647665.129, 133220282354.896, 136289389883.027, 
136105727596.639, 144012821510.279, 140567471427.412, 156523786662.561, 
132892247068.545, 157280299581.83, 155718681850.043, 156516154153.255, 
159377383636.23, 165885897553.447, 165864184227.553, 160116986466.382, 
157905823210.504, 164359372468.044, 159043575288.086, 154424287427.483, 
157682860574.848, 171185122967.931, 163305245643.467, 179439335670.685, 
177673116648.974, 168265386237.813, 170643639307.424, 176556004938.938, 
176104224230.554, 169432442084.016, 180720093492.274, 191253847922.428, 
191857717679.132, 188608772378.779, 187047208526.037, 180438693649.691, 
172335477103.03, 177451600820.397, 183067461351.504, 176464475457.028, 
185928194815.101, 191251069717.439, 187747141970.477, 210179745023.278, 
157241613741.851, 176914493158.296, 188675254279.379, 192442122672.855, 
184610369983.496, 203370122309.805, 200240211193.534, 203263410965.852, 
207225348630.231, 200160081536.388, 204625844493.643, 202468374371.914, 
233788144677.612, 151111383019.148, 176991608721.248, 186711011725.242, 
189005838808.14, 186454606260.161, 188770785962.463, 195141282197.096, 
192299099866.934, 185149517213.623, 199954688057.804, 178517239386.28, 
175626427010.434, 169074948272.991, 174455003446.448, 177932465390.993, 
177104006933.22, 174644985405.667, 182683896266.788, 175254871501.662, 
177577770801.49, 181783322867.315, 186517479970.691, 180673844425.014, 
166403059342.659, 189033762978.916, 180565212357.218, 186263427345.182, 
190945329651.339, 183835452297.594, 189985278889.584, 188138908229.734, 
187491670468.533, 202425247324.262, 206671306914.408, 198724540510.608, 
239191587576.058, 183647135578.025, 202960843318.38, 208859943824.772, 
211184341852.718, 204869275482.01, 208327579777.757, 214120628906.966, 
213905673401.96, 210310809468.398, 197681385498.037, 216113695146.12, 
189446904818.828, 209094764350.941, 198172312845.581, 211894731397.359, 
208277059559.218, 211606142136.694, 206640522407.632, 207424225205.557, 
211981166199.96, 207800742519.21, 214032937224.914, 208928196858.187, 
111940160021.434, 194234598476.417, 204612843107.898, 205396018760.827, 
208866921947.777, 225893959031.978, 225700995155.194, 226952863188.688, 
235140068992.209, 250748324727.657, 253110677677.01, 259384317245.02, 
283556171247.067, 252749220975.009, 270769931623.621, 262839032722.912, 
274970897130.162, 268167233309.258, 282491355088.301, 289627962447.681, 
297718562831.63, 305380540717.216, 306176644297.362, 320237212405.99, 
299804890651.788, 287329140623.924, 280284152136.147, 306482748887.16, 
321566172911.54, 316281719807.817, 303329008157.876, 305292305222.074, 
296620039752.443, 278608831325.749, 276379708506.143, 287071145870.506, 
295696421218.491, 328003015962.194, 303700120862.941, 283885425918.538
)), row.names = c(NA, -257L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```